# AWS Cloudfront redirecting form post to origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

Hi I have a dynamic application that has a search form. I'm trying to use CloudFront with a load balancer. When you do a search the application creates some URL parameters and reloads the page. For some reason cloudfront is doing a 302 redirect back to the origin. Does anybody know how to fix this?

I have the following configuration.

[image]

Comment: There's nothing in the origin server or load balancer logs for the 302? Can you capture the request and reaponse headers from this redirect?

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that you're going to want to turn on `Forward Query Strings`. Without it, cloudfront will treat the following urls as the same:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com?q=search_term
http://www.example.com?q=search_term&option=true
```

It's however not clear to me that this would result in 302 to the original url (btw. origin means something very specific when dealing with cloudfront/other cdns - it's often short for origin server which is the source behind the cdn)

The 302 redirect is much more likely to your `Viewer Protocol Policy`, which you have set http requests to redirect to http. You should double check that your application isn't reloading the http version of the page.